# Tag inside textarea in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have looked at all packages/plugins available for ReactJS but couldn't find anything like it. I'm trying to tag users in the `<textarea>` of my app something like the attached screen:

[image]

I understand this is for coding issues but I'm lost trying to figure out where to even start. Some direction would really help.

Comment: https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate check this. It has that feature. If you want pure custom one let me know.

Comment: Thank you but their website isn't working for demo. Does it have the dropdown/tags feature?

Comment: They have all features. https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/master/site/examples/mentions.js
and its highly customisable

Comment: Wow. This may work!! Thank you so much.

Comment: np. if it works dont forget to give a up vote on my comment. :D cheers

Comment: Thank You. I upvoted all your comments but I ended up using React-mentions since it's smaller and lighter. Slate also does what I need. Thank you once again :)

Comment: thanks. I have added comments ;)

Answer (score 0):

[check this](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate) check this. It has that feature. If you want pure custom one let me know.